# Cluster-tilting object for a local non-selfinjective algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a non-selfinjective (which is equivalent to non-Gorenstein) local finite dimensional algebra.

> Is there a known example of such an $A$ having a cluster-tilting object?

Id be surprised to see one, but Im not totally sure whether this question has been studied somewhere.